# How to avoid "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

I see the question already,but failed to get a working solution for the same.I'm new to protractor.Please provide a solution.
I m using protrator 5,chrome version 65,also using protractor for creating an POC for React JS website.

```
 var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config={
    framework:'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress:'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs:['../SpecFiles/*.js'],
    capablities:{
       'browserName':'chrome'
    },
    params:{
        common: {
            url: "XXXX",
            userName:"XXXXXX",
            password: "viktest12345",
            testData: require('../ElementLocators/elements.json')
        }
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000000000000000000000
    },
    "globals": {
        "browser": false},
    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
                savePath: 'target/screenshots'
            })
        );

    }
}

test:


var waitForUrlToChangeTo = require('../globalMethods').x;

describe("Login Functionality",function()
{

    beforeEach(function() {
/*      originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000000000;*/
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get(browser.params.common.url);
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    });

    it("login Functionality with valid credentials", function () {
        console.log("Login with valid credentials");
        element(by.name(browser.params.common.testData.login.login_userName)).getWebElement().sendKeys(browser.params.common.userName);
        browser.driver.findElement(by.name(browser.params.common.testData.login.login_password)).sendKeys(browser.params.common.password);
        browser.findElement(by.buttonText(browser.params.common.testData.login.login_submit)).click();
        waitForUrlToChangeTo(new RegExp(browser.params.common.testData.dashboard.url));
        var pageHeading = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath(browser.params.common.testData.dashboard.page_Heading)).getText();
        expect(pageHeading).toBe("Dashboard");
        });
});
```

I tried default timeout setting in config.js,also in the before each block,also as a third parameter for the describe block.none of the solution works.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As per the **protractor documentation** , protractor click/sendKeys returns

> A promise that will be resolved when the click/sendKeys command has completed.

You can try using **async/await** here !
For Example :

```
it('demo test', async ()=>{
  await browser.findElement(by.buttonText(browser.params.common.testData.login.login_submit)).click();
 });
```

Read more from [protrator documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys)